# Local form of complex structure via Bruhat-Whitney

Tags: complex-geometry, almost-complex

**Set-up**: Let $(L,g)$ be a real-analytic riemannian manifold. And let $T^*L$ denote the cotangent bundle of $L$.

According to Bruhat-Whitney, on a suffciently small neigbourhood of the zero section in $T^*L$ there exists a complex structure $J$ which is unique up to biholomorphism.

The zero section $L \subset T^*L$ is Lagrangian and thus totally real. By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922780/local-property-of-real-submanifold-embedded-in-complex-space) real analytic and totally real means we can find local holomorphic coordinates $\{z_i = x_i +i y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $L = \{y =0\}$.

**Question**: Does it follow that in these coordinates the complex structure $J$ on this neighborhood of $L$ in $T^*L$ is given by
$$
J\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}= \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}, \quad J\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}= -\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}?
$$